# Holding dynamic until all options are chosen for an interactive plot

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I want to control the variables (and other options) used in a plot through a number of popup menus. As the plot takes a little time to be drawn, I want to be able to make a selection on each of the popup menus before the plot is drawn.

As a bonus challenge, I'd like the user to be able to control when the plot is drawn by pressing a button - however, I want to deploy this using Mathematica Online and `Button` cannot be cloud deployed.

Below is a toy example of my code so far. I use dynamic to link the popup menus to the plot. The problem is that it is a little *too* dynamic. I have tried using hold and unevaluated, then releasing/evaluating with a button but I couldn't get it to work.

```
(* create an association of variable values (random numbers) and variable names, a to e *)
values = AssociationThread[CharacterRange["a", "e"],RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 10}]];

(* define variable names *)
vars = Keys@values;

DynamicModule[{xvalue, yvalue},{
(* x value popup menu *)
PopupMenu[Dynamic[xvalue], vars],
(* x value popup menu *)
PopupMenu[Dynamic[yvalue], vars],
(* the plot *)
Dynamic[ListPlot[Transpose[{values[xvalue], values[yvalue]}]]]}]
```

So my two questions are:

1. How can I let the user control the evaluation of the plot such that they can choose all options from popup menus before evaluating the plot?
2. Is there a cloud-deployable alternative to `Button`?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second argument of `Dynamic` so that the plot changes only after the y popup menu is selected.

```
DynamicModule[{x0 = "a", xvalue = "a", y0 = "a", yvalue = "a"},
 {(* x value popup menu *)
  PopupMenu[Dynamic[x0], vars],
  (* y value popup menu *)
  PopupMenu[Dynamic[y0,
    (xvalue = x0; yvalue = y0 = #) &], vars],
  (* the plot *)
  Dynamic[ListPlot[Transpose[{values[xvalue], values[yvalue]}]]]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!